# Whitespace validation in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I want the user to prevent from adding white space when he clicks on submit button . I am displaying the alert message in handle change so if the user adds a space it will show.

But i want to show the alert message in handlesubmit.

Below is my code:

```
 handleChange(event) {
    let reWhiteSpace = new RegExp(/\s/);
    var errors = {}
     if (event.target.id === 'userID') {
        this.setState({ userID: event.target.value })
        errors.userID = reWhiteSpace.test(event.target.value)
        if (errors.userID) {
            this.setState({
                alertMessage: "Spacing Not Allowed",
                showAlert: true,
                alertcolor: "warning"
            })
        } 
    }

    this.setState({
        errors: errors
    })
}

 handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('form submission data', this.state);
    var data = this.state;
    if (this.state.userID !== '' ) {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }),
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        };
        console.log(requestOptions)
        fetch(API_URL, requestOptions)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data)
                if (data.status) {
                    window.location = '/user-list'
                    if (data.message !== "") {
                        this.setState({
                            alertMessage: data.message,
                            showAlert: true,
                            alertcolor: "success"
                        })
                    }
                }
                else if (data.message !== "") {
                    console.log('else', data.message)
                    this.setState({
                        alertMessage: data.message,
                        showAlert: true,
                        alertcolor: "warning"
                    })
                }
            })
            .catch(console.log)
    }
    else {
        this.setState({
            alertMessage: "Please enter all required fields",
            showAlert: true,
            alertcolor: "warning"
        })
    }
}
```

I want to check the white space validation in handle submit
Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use the `this.state.errors.userID` to check this in `handleSubmit`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you store the `errors` in the state you can also check it in `handleSubmit`:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.errors && this.state.errors.userID) {
        this.setState({
            alertMessage: "Please enter all required fields",
            showAlert: true,
            alertcolor: "warning"
        })
        return;
    }

    console.log('form submission data', this.state);
    var data = this.state;
    if (this.state.userID !== '' ) {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
            }),
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        };
        console.log(requestOptions)
        fetch(API_URL, requestOptions)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data)
                if (data.status) {
                    window.location = '/user-list'
                    if (data.message !== "") {
                        this.setState({
                            alertMessage: data.message,
                            showAlert: true,
                            alertcolor: "success"
                        })
                    }
                }
                else if (data.message !== "") {
                    console.log('else', data.message)
                    this.setState({
                        alertMessage: data.message,
                        showAlert: true,
                        alertcolor: "warning"
                    })
                }
            })
            .catch(console.log)
    }
    else {
        this.setState({
            alertMessage: "Please enter all required fields",
            showAlert: true,
            alertcolor: "warning"
        })
    }
}
```

If you want to check for white space only at the start/end of the string you can use the `trim()` method instead of your regex:

```
function checkWhiteSpace(text) {
  const _text = text.trim();
  return text === _text;
}
```

You could also avoid all this white space validation and remove it programmatically before sending your request with the `string.trim()` method. You can [read more here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)

Comment: it is allowing only if 2 words are added . Single word is not accepting

Comment: What do you mean by that? Your regex doesn't work? I've added a different check